# Updating a parent when all children meet certain criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `salesorders` the parent, and `invoices` the child.  I have a stored procedure run inside a trigger that runs after every update to the `invoices` table.  I want to add an `UPDATE` statement to this stored procedure.

Right now, both `salesorders` and `invoices` have a `state` column.  What I want to do is update the sales order state to `0` if and only if EVERY child invoice has a state of 4 or greater. Some of the invoice states are `NULL` as well, and in the case where I have 3 invoices where 2 of them have a state of 4 or more, and 1 of them is a NULL, I do NOT want to update the sales order `state` to 0.

I was thinking of comparing the total number of invoices per sales order to the number where invoice state > 4, but I still can't seem to get it working right.  How can I go about this?

Comment: Would you please add your code to your question?  Some sample data and requested output would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

First, I would question if you really need this.  Can you optimize the database so a query looking at a single sale can easily gather all the invoices together to check the condition?

If not, then consider a trigger.  Because this is a trigger, things can get tricky.  I would recommend adding a column that specifies *how many invoices do not meet the condition*.

You can keep this up-to-date by only looking at the current row -- although it does require comparing the `new` and `old` values.

Then you can use this value for the logic about the state of the sale.

Comment: I do need this as a automatic feature.  My boss wants it such that when all invoices meet a criteria, the sales order state is automatically set.  Yea I've taken the column route before.  I suppose then I would really need two columns then?  One for total invoices, one for invoices that are state 4 or more, and if they match, ok set state to 0, else do nothing?

Comment: So really in my invoices trigger, it'd be two updates, one to update the sales order invoice state count, and then one to update the sales order state based on that count, right?

Comment: @bjk116 . . . That is one approach.  If you count down, then the state you want is when the count is zero.  Of course, if you require at least one invoice, then you need two columns (although they can be updated in the same `update` statement).